# Caption for a table in landscape environment

Tags: tables, landscape

I want to insert a caption for a table in the landscape environment but can't find a way to do it.

```
\begin{landscape}
    \pagestyle{empty}%
    \resizebox{0,1\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline 
            &  \\ 
            \hline 
            &  \\ 
            \hline 
        \end{tabular} }
    \end{landscape}
```

Comment: you can just use `\caption` inside `table` inside `landscape` just as for a normal table (it is best to avoid `\resizebox` on `tabular` though`

Comment: without the \resizebox my table is too big for the page. Which is the best way to change the size of a table in the tabular environment?

Comment: resizebox just produces horribly inconsistent fonts, you would not justify paragraph text by scaling so why tables? see any one of a thousand answers on this site for controlling table width, use `\small` or use a column like `p{3cm}` instead of `c` so you can have linebreaking within the cells or ....

Comment: @Eleonora: Note that `0,1\textwidth` should probably be `0.1\textwidth`.

Answer (score 1):

You could load the `rotating` package and make use of its `sidewaystable` environment to typeset both the caption and the tabular material in landscape mode.

Oh, and I wouldn't the `\resizebox` method unless all other, more reasonable methods have already been exhausted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{A table in landscape format}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & 
abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc & abc \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}%
} % end of scope of \resizebox
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some examples to illustrate the suggestions given in the comments to your question are in order. In particular, if you use the `p` column type suggested by David, you might not need a `landscape` environment after all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{
    lscape,
    lipsum  % just to obtain some filler text
}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}%

\begin{landscape}
\small

\begin{table}
\caption{Pokemons of the world}

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\linewidth}|p{0.5\linewidth}|}
    \hline 
    Before &  After \\ 
    \hline 
    \lipsum[1-2]  & \lipsum[2] \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{landscape}

\begin{table}

\caption{Pokemons of the world}

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.7\linewidth}|p{0.3\linewidth}|}
    \hline 
    Before &  After \\ 
    \hline 
    \lipsum[1-2]  & \lipsum[2] \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}


\end{document}
```